# Converting Numbers to Words in MYSQL result! Using Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I am trying to print a output as follows when I execute a query in mysql.

```
Name    Salary  Sal_in_Words
Mohan   45000   Rupees Forty Five Thousand Only
```

The column Salary has a value 45000 and in the third column the Value in second colunm is converted to words through Query.

I found some article where in Oracle we can get the result as above using the below query:

```
select Salary, (' Rs. '|| (to_char(to_date(sal,'j'), 'Jsp'))|| ' only.')) Sal_in_Words from employee
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name    Salary  Sal_in_Words
Suresh  45000   Rupees Forty Five Thousand Only
```

In MySQL I tried LPAD,RPAD but those just adds strings to the result not converting words to string.

I found some tutorial but all those explained about "TO_CHAR (dates)".

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicates
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819571/converting-a-number-into-a-word-in-mysql

Comment: But when I run the last example I got the following error.                 #1418 - This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: TO_CHAR does not exist

Comment: than i think you have to create a custom function in mysql

Comment: Will It increase the speed of the query execution..? because each time when It calls the function.. that function will take time.. rite.. That's why I am opting for an inbuilt MySQL Command.

Comment: have u seen this 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `number_to_string`(n INT) RETURNS varchar(100)
BEGIN
.
.
.
you have to create a mysql function and i dont think so it will burden for mysql.

Comment: Yes.. I saw it and while I am trying that I got the following error..  #1418 - This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you might want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1; use this than create your functions

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29588/discussion-between-ajay-patel-and-tomphp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
PROCEDURE TO GENERATE NUMBER TO WORDS FORMAT...........

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `xnum2txt`(in nNum int(8))
BEGIN
   declare cRetVal,cTxt,cX1,cX2 varchar(500);
    set nNum=floor(nNum);
    set cRetval='';
    set cTxt='';
            if nnum<0 then
                set cRetval="-"+ xNum22Txt(nnum*-1);
            elseif nNum<11 then 
                set cTxt="Zero One  Two  ThreeFour Five Six  SevenEightNine Ten  ";
                set cRetVal= trim(substring(cTxt,(nNum * 5) + 1,5)) ;
            ELSEIF nNum < 20 then 
                set cTxt = "Eleven   Twelve   Thirteen Fourteen Fifteen  Sixteen  SeventeenEighteen Nineteen ";
                set cRetval = trim(substring(cTxt,((nNum - 11) * 9) + 1,9));
            ELSEIF nNum < 30 then
                  set cRetval = "Twenty" + if(nNum > 20,"-" + xnum22txt(nNum-20)," ");
            ELSEIF nNum < 40 then
                  set cRetval = "Thirty" + if(nNum > 30,"-" + xnum22txt(nNum-30)," ");
            ELSEIF nNum < 50 then 
                  set cRetval = "Forty" + if(nNum > 40,"-" + xnum22txt(nNum-40)," ");
            ELSEIF nNum < 60 then
                  set cRetval = "Fifty" + if(nNum > 50,"-" + xnum22txt(nNum-50)," ");
            ELSEIF nNum < 70 then
                  set cRetval = "Sixty" + if(nNum > 60,"-" + xnum22txt(nNum-60)," ");
            ELSEIF nNum < 80 then
                  set cRetval = "Seventy" + if(nNum > 70,"-" + xnum22txt(nNum-70)," ");
            ELSEIF nNum < 90 then
                  set cRetval = "Eighty" + if(nNum > 80,"-" + xnum22txt(nNum-80)," ");
            ELSEIF nNum < 100 then
                  set cRetval = "Ninety" + if(nNum > 90,"-" + xnum22txt(nNum-90)," ");
            ELSEIF nNum < 1000 then
                  set cX1 = floor(nNum/100);
                  set cX2 = nNum-(cX1*100);
                  set cRetval = xnum22txt(cX1) + "Hundred" + if(cX2 > 0," " + xnum22txt(cX2)," ");
           ELSEIF nNum < 1000000 then
                  set cX1 = floor(nNum/1000);
                  set cX2 = nNum-(cX1*1000);
                  set cRetval = xnum22txt(cX1) + "Thousand" + if(cX2 > 0,", " + xnum22txt(cX2)," ");
           ELSEIF nNum < 1000000000 then
                  set cX1 = floor(nNum/1000000);
                  set cX2 = nNum-(cX1*1000000);
                  set cRetval = xnum22txt(cX1) + "Million" + if(cX2 > 0,", " + xnum22txt(cX2)," ");
           ELSEIF nNum < 1000000000000 then
                  set cX1 = floor(nNum/1000000000);
                  set cX2 = nNum-(cX1*1000000000);
                  set cRetval = xnum22txt(cX1) + "Billion" + if(cX2 > 0,", " + xnum22txt(cX2)," ");
            ELSE
                  set cRetval = "***";
            end if;
            select cRetVal;
END
```

Comment: @XMozart, you were supposed to run "call xnum2txt(n)" and not "select xnum2txt(n)"

Answer (score 3):

There is not simple function in MySQL you need to write a function with the help of the function you can achieve this result.

Check the following.. It works for me.. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819571/converting-a-number-into-a-word-in-mysql)

```
   DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION `number_to_string`(n INT) RETURNS varchar(100)
    BEGIN
        -- This function returns the string representation of a number.
        -- It's just an example... I'll restrict it to hundreds, but
        -- it can be extended easily.
        -- The idea is: 
        --      For each digit you need a position,
        --      For each position, you assign a string
        declare ans varchar(100);
        declare dig1, dig2, dig3 int; -- (one variable per digit)

        set ans = '';

        set dig3 = floor(n / 100);
        set dig2 = floor(n / 10) - dig3*10;
        set dig1 = n - (dig3*100 + dig2*10);

        if dig3 > 0 then
            case
                when dig3=1 then set ans=concat(ans, 'one hundred');
                when dig3=2 then set ans=concat(ans, 'two hundred');
                when dig3=3 then set ans=concat(ans, 'three hundred');
                when dig3=4 then set ans=concat(ans, 'four hundred');
                when dig3=5 then set ans=concat(ans, 'five hundred');
                when dig3=6 then set ans=concat(ans, 'six hundred');
                when dig3=7 then set ans=concat(ans, 'seven hundred');
                when dig3=8 then set ans=concat(ans, 'eight hundred');
                when dig3=9 then set ans=concat(ans, 'nine hundred');
                else set ans = ans;
            end case;
        end if;

        if dig2 = 1 then
            case
                when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans,' ten');
                when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans,' eleven');
                when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans,' twelve');
                when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans,' thirteen');
                when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans,' fourteen');
                when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans,' fifteen');
                when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans,' sixteen');
                when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans,' seventeen');
                when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans,' eighteen');
                when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans,' nineteen');
                else set ans=ans;
            end case;
        else
            if dig2 > 0 then
                case
                    when dig2=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' twenty');
                    when dig2=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' thirty');
                    when dig2=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fourty');
                    when dig2=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fifty');
                    when dig2=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' sixty');
                    when dig2=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seventy');
                    when dig2=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eighty');
                    when dig2=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' ninety');
                    else set ans=ans;
                end case;
            end if;
            if dig1 > 0 then
                case
                    when dig1=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' one');
                    when dig1=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' two');
                    when dig1=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' three');
                    when dig1=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' four');
                    when dig1=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' five');
                    when dig1=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' six');
                    when dig1=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seven');
                    when dig1=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eight');
                    when dig1=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' nine');
                    else set ans=ans;
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;

        return trim(ans);
    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

If get the following error..

```
#1418 - This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you might want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

Run this query:

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
```

After that Create a function in Mysql:

Call the function Just like the below command:

```
SELECT number_to_string( 666 );
```

You will get the output as:

```
number_to_string( 666 )
six hundred sixty six
```

Hope this will help for others!

Answer (score 2):

I took TomPHP's answer and extended it to work up to 6 digits:

`SELECT number_into_words(999999);` would result in `nine hundred ninety nine thousand nine hundred ninety nine`

I also updated the initial setting of `dig1` through `dig6` so it was more readable to myself (I understand that there are more efficient ways to do this).

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `number_to_words`(n INT) RETURNS varchar(100)
BEGIN
    -- This function returns the string representation of a number.
    -- It's just an example... I'll restrict it to hundreds, but
    -- it can be extended easily.
    -- The idea is:
    --      For each digit you need a position,
    --      For each position, you assign a string
    declare ans varchar(100);
    declare dig1, dig2, dig3, dig4, dig5, dig6 int;

set ans = '';

set dig6 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 100000) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig5 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 10000) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig4 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 1000) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig3 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 100) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig2 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 10) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig1 = CAST(RIGHT(floor(n), 1) as SIGNED);

if dig6 > 0 then
    case
        when dig6=1 then set ans=concat(ans, 'one hundred');
        when dig6=2 then set ans=concat(ans, 'two hundred');
        when dig6=3 then set ans=concat(ans, 'three hundred');
        when dig6=4 then set ans=concat(ans, 'four hundred');
        when dig6=5 then set ans=concat(ans, 'five hundred');
        when dig6=6 then set ans=concat(ans, 'six hundred');
        when dig6=7 then set ans=concat(ans, 'seven hundred');
        when dig6=8 then set ans=concat(ans, 'eight hundred');
        when dig6=9 then set ans=concat(ans, 'nine hundred');
        else set ans = ans;
    end case;
end if;

if dig5 = 1 then
    case
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans, ' ten thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eleven thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans, ' twelve thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans, ' thirteen thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fourteen thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fifteen thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans, ' sixteen thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seventeen thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eighteen thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans, ' nineteen thousand ');
        else set ans=ans;
    end case;
else
    if dig5 > 0 then
        case
            when dig5=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' twenty');
            when dig5=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' thirty');
            when dig5=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fourty');
            when dig5=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fifty');
            when dig5=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' sixty');
            when dig5=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seventy');
            when dig5=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eighty');
            when dig5=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' ninety');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
    if dig4 > 0 then
        case
            when dig4=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' one thousand ');
            when dig4=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' two thousand ');
            when dig4=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' three thousand ');
            when dig4=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' four thousand ');
            when dig4=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' five thousand ');
            when dig4=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' six thousand ');
            when dig4=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seven thousand ');
            when dig4=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eight thousand ');
            when dig4=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' nine thousand ');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
    if dig4 = 0 AND (dig5 != 0 || dig6 != 0) then
        set ans=concat(ans, ' thousand ');
    end if;
end if;

if dig3 > 0 then
    case
        when dig3=1 then set ans=concat(ans, 'one hundred');
        when dig3=2 then set ans=concat(ans, 'two hundred');
        when dig3=3 then set ans=concat(ans, 'three hundred');
        when dig3=4 then set ans=concat(ans, 'four hundred');
        when dig3=5 then set ans=concat(ans, 'five hundred');
        when dig3=6 then set ans=concat(ans, 'six hundred');
        when dig3=7 then set ans=concat(ans, 'seven hundred');
        when dig3=8 then set ans=concat(ans, 'eight hundred');
        when dig3=9 then set ans=concat(ans, 'nine hundred');
        else set ans = ans;
    end case;
end if;

if dig2 = 1 then
    case
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans, ' ten');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eleven');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans, ' twelve');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans, ' thirteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fourteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fifteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans, ' sixteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seventeen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eighteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans, ' nineteen');
        else set ans=ans;
    end case;
else
    if dig2 > 0 then
        case
            when dig2=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' twenty');
            when dig2=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' thirty');
            when dig2=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fourty');
            when dig2=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fifty');
            when dig2=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' sixty');
            when dig2=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seventy');
            when dig2=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eighty');
            when dig2=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' ninety');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
    if dig1 > 0 then
        case
            when dig1=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' one');
            when dig1=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' two');
            when dig1=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' three');
            when dig1=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' four');
            when dig1=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' five');
            when dig1=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' six');
            when dig1=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seven');
            when dig1=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eight');
            when dig1=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' nine');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
end if;

return trim(ans);
END
$$
```

Comment: How to Add upto 1 crore rupees? Thanks

Comment: @Phoenix - I am not sure what you are asking.  What is "cror rupees"?

Comment: How to convert 1 crore rupees in INR? Can you understand now? That means Indian Standard.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql Function in Indian Standard

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `number_to_string`(n INT) RETURNS varchar(1000) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    declare ans varchar(1000);
    declare dig1, dig2, dig3,dig4,dig5,dig6,dig7,dig8,dig9 int;

    set ans = '';
    set dig9 = floor(n/100000000);
    set dig8 = floor(n/10000000) - dig9*10;
    set dig7 = floor(n/1000000) -(floor(n/10000000)*10);
    set dig6 = floor(n/100000) - (floor(n/1000000)*10);
    set dig5 = floor(n/10000) -  (floor(n/100000)*10);
    set dig4 = floor(n/1000) -   (floor(n/10000)*10);
    set dig3 = floor(n/100) -    (floor(n/1000)*10);
    set dig2 = floor(n/10) -     (floor(n/100)*10);
    set dig1 = n - (floor(n / 10)*10);
if dig7 = 1 then
        case
            when (dig7*10 + dig6) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans,'Ten Lakhs');
            when (dig7*10 + dig6) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eleven Lakhs');
            when (dig7*10 + dig6) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans,'Twelve Lakhs');
            when (dig7*10 + dig6) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans,'Thirteen Lakhs');
            when (dig7*10 + dig6) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fourteen Lakhs');
            when (dig7*10 + dig6) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fifteen Lakhs');
            when (dig7*10 + dig6) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans,'Sixteen Lakhs');
            when (dig7*10 + dig6) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans,'Seventeen Lakhs');
            when (dig7*10 + dig6) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eighteen Lakhs');
            when (dig7*10 + dig6) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans,'Nineteen Lakhs');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    else
        if dig7 > 0 then
            case
                when dig7=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Twenty');
                when dig7=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Thirty');
                when dig7=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fourty');
                when dig7=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fifty');
                when dig7=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Sixty');
                when dig7=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seventy');
                when dig7=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eighty');
                when dig7=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Ninety');
                else set ans=ans;
            end case;
            if ans <> '' and dig6 =0 then
            set ans=concat(ans, ' Thousand');
            end if;
        end if;
        if ans <> '' and dig6 > 0 and dig7 =0 then
        set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
        end if;
        if dig6 > 0 then
        case
            when dig6=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' One Lakhs');
            when dig6=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Two Lakhs');
            when dig6=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Three Lakhs');
            when dig6=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Four Lakhs');
            when dig6=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Five Lakhs');
            when dig6=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Six Lakhs');
            when dig6=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seven Lakhs');
            when dig6=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eight Lakhs');
            when dig6=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Nine Lakhs');
            else set ans = ans;
        end case;
    end if;
end if;
    if ans <> '' and dig5 > 0 then
        set ans=concat(ans, '');
    end if;
    if dig5 = 1 then
        case
            when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans,'Ten Thousand');
            when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eleven Thousand');
            when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans,'Twelve Thousand');
            when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans,'Thirteen Thousand');
            when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fourteen Thousand');
            when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fifteen Thousand');
            when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans,'Sixteen Thousand');
            when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans,'Seventeen Thousand');
            when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eighteen Thousand');
            when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans,'Nineteen Thousand');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    else
        if dig5 > 0 then
            case
                when dig5=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Twenty');
                when dig5=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Thirty');
                when dig5=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fourty');
                when dig5=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fifty');
                when dig5=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Sixty');
                when dig5=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seventy');
                when dig5=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eighty');
                when dig5=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Ninety');
                else set ans=ans;
            end case;
            if ans <> '' and dig4 =0 then
            set ans=concat(ans, ' Thousand');
            end if;
        end if;
        if ans <> '' and dig4 > 0 and dig5 =0 then
        set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
        end if;
        if dig4 > 0 then
        case
            when dig4=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' One Thousand');
            when dig4=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Two Thousand');
            when dig4=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Three Thousand');
            when dig4=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Four Thousand');
            when dig4=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Five Thousand');
            when dig4=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Six Thousand');
            when dig4=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seven Thousand');
            when dig4=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eight Thousand');
            when dig4=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Nine Thousand');
            else set ans = ans;
        end case;
    end if;
end if;
    if ans <> '' and dig3 > 0 then
        set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
    end if;
    if dig3 > 0 then
        case
            when dig3=1 then set ans=concat(ans, 'One Hundred');
            when dig3=2 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Two Hundred');
            when dig3=3 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Three Hundred');
            when dig3=4 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Four Hundred');
            when dig3=5 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Five Hundred');
            when dig3=6 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Six Hundred');
            when dig3=7 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Seven Hundred');
            when dig3=8 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Eight Hundred');
            when dig3=9 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Nine Hundred');
            else set ans = ans;
        end case;
    end if;
    if ans <> '' and dig2 > 0 then
        set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
    end if;
    if dig2 = 1 then
        case
            when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans,'Ten');
            when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eleven');
            when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans,'Twelve');
            when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans,'Thirteen');
            when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fourteen');
            when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fifteen');
            when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans,'Sixteen');
            when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans,'Seventeen');
            when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eighteen');
            when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans,'Nineteen');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    else
        if dig2 > 0 then
            case
                when dig2=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Twenty');
                when dig2=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Thirty');
                when dig2=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fourty');
                when dig2=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fifty');
                when dig2=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Sixty');
                when dig2=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seventy');
                when dig2=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eighty');
                when dig2=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Ninety');
                else set ans=ans;
            end case;
        end if;
        if ans <> '' and dig1 > 0 and dig2 =0 then
        set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
        end if;
        if dig1 > 0 then
            case
                when dig1=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' One');
                when dig1=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Two');
                when dig1=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Three');
                when dig1=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Four');
                when dig1=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Five');
                when dig1=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Six');
                when dig1=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seven');
                when dig1=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eight');
                when dig1=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Nine');
                else set ans=ans;
            end case;
        end if;
    end if;

    return trim(ans);
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FUNCTION `fn_number2words`(_Number double(18,2)) 
       RETURNS varchar(8000) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE _inputNumber VARCHAR(38);
        DECLARE _outputString VARCHAR(8000);
        DECLARE _length INT;
        DECLARE _counter INT;
        DECLARE _loops INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE _position INT;
        DECLARE _chunk CHAR(3); -- for chunks of 3 numbers
        DECLARE _tensones CHAR(2);
        DECLARE _hundreds CHAR(1);
        DECLARE _tens CHAR(1);
        DECLARE _ones CHAR(1);
        DECLARE _cents varchar(50);
        DECLARE _numtmp1 varchar(50);
        DECLARE _numtmp2 varchar(50);
        DECLARE _numtmp3 varchar(50);

IF _Number = 0 THEN
        SET _outputString = 'Zero';
    ELSE
        SET _cents = REPLACE(CAST((_Number % 1)*100 as char), '.00', '');
    -- initialize the variables
    SELECT  REPLACE(CAST((_Number - (_Number % 1)) as char), '.00', ''),
            '',
            1
     INTO _inputNumber, _outputString, _counter;

        IF MOD(LENGTH(_inputNumber), 3) = 1 THEN
            SET _inputNumber = CONCAT('00', _inputNumber);
        ELSEIF  MOD(LENGTH(_inputNumber), 3) = 2 THEN
            SET _inputNumber = CONCAT('0', _inputNumber);
        END IF;

     SELECT LENGTH(_inputNumber),
                    (LENGTH(_inputNumber)/3),
                    LENGTH(_inputNumber)/3
     INTO _length, _position, _loops;

        WHILE _counter <= _loops DO

        SET _chunk = SUBSTR(_inputNumber, ((_position-1)*3)+1, 3);

        IF _chunk <> '000' THEN
            SELECT 
            SUBSTR(_chunk, 2, 2), SUBSTR(_chunk, 1, 1), SUBSTR(_chunk, 2, 1), SUBSTR(_chunk, 3, 1)
            INTO
             _tensones,
             _hundreds,
             _tens,
             _ones;

             /*SELECT _inputNumber, _chunk, _tensones, _hundreds, _tens, _ones, _counter, _position, _loops, CAST(_tensones as UNSIGNED INT);*/

             IF CAST(_tensones as UNSIGNED) <= 20 OR _ones='0' THEN
                SELECT word INTO _numtmp1 FROM tbl_numbers WHERE number = _tensones;
                SELECT CASE _counter 
                       WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                       WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                       WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                       WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                       WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                       WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                       WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '  WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                       ELSE '' END 
                       INTO _numtmp2;
                SET _outputString = CONCAT(_numtmp1, _numtmp2, _outputString);
             ELSE
                SELECT word INTO _numtmp1 FROM tbl_numbers WHERE number = CONCAT(_tens,'0');
                SELECT word INTO _numtmp2 FROM tbl_numbers WHERE number = CONCAT('0',_ones);
                SELECT CASE _counter WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                       WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                       WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                       WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                       WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                       WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                       WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '   WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                       ELSE '' END
                       INTO _numtmp3;

                SET _outputString = CONCAT(' ',_numtmp1, '-',_numtmp2, _numtmp3, _outputString);

             END IF;

             -- now get the hundreds
            IF _hundreds <> '0' THEN
                SELECT word INTO _numtmp1 FROM tbl_numbers WHERE number = CONCAT('0',_hundreds);
                SET _outputString = CONCAT(_numtmp1, ' hundred ', _outputString);
            END IF;
        END IF;
        /* seed variables */
        SELECT (_counter+1), (_position-1) 
            INTO _counter, _position;

        END WHILE;
 END IF;
 IF RTRIM(LTRIM(_outputString)) = '' THEN
    SET _outputString = '';
 ELSE
    SET _outputString = CONCAT(_outputString, ' PESOS AND ');
 END IF;
 SET _outputString = UPPER(CONCAT(_outputString,_cents,'/100 CENT(S)')); -- return the result
 RETURN _outputString;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `number_to_words`(`n` DECIMAL(10,2)) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    declare ans varchar(100);
    declare dig1, dig2, dig3, dig4, dig5, dig6 int;

DECLARE num1,num2 varchar(100);
set ans = '';
IF n != '' THEN  // Check is Blank Argument 

set num1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(n, ".", 1);
set num2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(n, '.', -1);

set dig6 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(num1 / 100000) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig5 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(num1 / 10000) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig4 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(num1 / 1000) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig3 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(num1 / 100) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig2 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(num1 / 10) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig1 = CAST(RIGHT(floor(num1), 1) as SIGNED);

IF num1 != '' then
if dig6 > 0 then
    case
        when dig6=1 then set ans=concat(ans, 'One Hundred');
        when dig6=2 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Two Hundred');
        when dig6=3 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Three Hundred');
        when dig6=4 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Four Hundred');
        when dig6=5 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Five Hundred');
        when dig6=6 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Six Hundred');
        when dig6=7 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Seven Hundred');
        when dig6=8 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Eight Hundred');
        when dig6=9 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Nine Hundred');
        else set ans = ans;
    end case;
end if;

if dig5 = 1 then
    case
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Ten Thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eleven Thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Twelve Thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Thirteen Thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fourteen Thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fifteen Thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Sixteen Thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seventeen Thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eighteen Thousand ');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Nineteen Thousand ');
        else set ans=ans;
    end case;
else
    if dig5 > 0 then
        case
            when dig5=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Twenty');
            when dig5=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Thirty');
            when dig5=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fourty');
            when dig5=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fifty');
            when dig5=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Sixty');
            when dig5=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seventy');
            when dig5=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eighty');
            when dig5=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Ninety');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
    if dig4 > 0 then
        case
            when dig4=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' One Thousand ');
            when dig4=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Two Thousand ');
            when dig4=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Three Thousand ');
            when dig4=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Four Thousand ');
            when dig4=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Five Thousand ');
            when dig4=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Six Thousand ');
            when dig4=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seven Thousand ');
            when dig4=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eight Thousand ');
            when dig4=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Nine Thousand ');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
    if dig4 = 0 AND (dig5 != 0 || dig6 != 0) then
        set ans=concat(ans, ' Thousand ');
    end if;
end if;

if dig3 > 0 then
    case
        when dig3=1 then set ans=concat(ans, 'One Hundred');
        when dig3=2 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Two Hundred');
        when dig3=3 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Three Hundred');
        when dig3=4 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Four Hundred');
        when dig3=5 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Five Hundred');
        when dig3=6 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Six Hundred');
        when dig3=7 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Seven Hundred');
        when dig3=8 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Eight Hundred');
        when dig3=9 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Nine Hundred');
        else set ans = ans;
    end case;
end if;

if dig2 = 1 then
    case
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Ten');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eleven');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Twelve');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Thirteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fourteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fifteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Sixteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seventeen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eighteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Nineteen');
        else set ans=ans;
    end case;
else
    if dig2 > 0 then
        case
            when dig2=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Twenty');
            when dig2=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Thirty');
            when dig2=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fourty');
            when dig2=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fifty');
            when dig2=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Sixty');
            when dig2=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seventy');
            when dig2=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eighty');
            when dig2=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Ninety');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
    if dig1 >= 0 then
        case
            when dig1=0 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Zero');
            when dig1=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' One');
            when dig1=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Two');
            when dig1=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Three');
            when dig1=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Four');
            when dig1=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Five');
            when dig1=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Six');
            when dig1=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seven');
            when dig1=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eight');
            when dig1=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Nine');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
end if;
end if;
IF num2 > 0 then
    set dig2 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(num2 / 10) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
    set dig1 = CAST(RIGHT(floor(num2), 1) as SIGNED);
    set ans=concat(ans, ' POINT ');

    if dig2 > 0 then
        case
            when dig2=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Twenty');
            when dig2=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Thirty');
            when dig2=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fourty');
            when dig2=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fifty');
            when dig2=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Sixty');
            when dig2=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seventy');
            when dig2=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eighty');
            when dig2=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Ninety');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
    if dig1 > 0 then
        case
            when dig1=0 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Zero');
            when dig1=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' One');
            when dig1=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Two');
            when dig1=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Three');
            when dig1=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Four');
            when dig1=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' five');
            when dig1=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Six');
            when dig1=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seven');
            when dig1=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eight');
            when dig1=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Nine');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
END IF;
END IF;

return trim(ans);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop function number_to_words;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `number_to_words`(n INT) RETURNS varchar(100)
BEGIN
-- This function returns the string representation of a number.
-- Took it from StackOverflow and Improved to return up to 8 digits in Indian Numbering system 
-- Upto:   9,99,99,999/-
-- which is:  "Nine Crore  Ninety Nine Lakh Ninety Nine Thousand  Nine Hundred Ninety Nine"
-- it can be extended further.
-- The idea is:
--      For each digit you need a position,
--      For each position, you assign a string
declare ans varchar(100);
declare dig1, dig2, dig3, dig4, dig5, dig6, dig7, dig8 int;

set ans = '';
set dig8 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 10000000) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig7 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 1000000) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig6 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 100000) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig5 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 10000) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig4 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 1000) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig3 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 100) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig2 = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(floor(n / 10) as CHAR(8)), 1) as SIGNED);
set dig1 = CAST(RIGHT(floor(n), 1) as SIGNED);

if dig8 > 0 then
case
    when dig8=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' one crore ');
    when dig8=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' two crore ');
    when dig8=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' three crore ');
    when dig8=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' four crore ');
    when dig8=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' five crore ');
    when dig8=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' six crore ');
    when dig8=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seven crore ');
    when dig8=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eight crore ');
    when dig8=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' nine crore ');
    
    else set ans = ans;
end case;
end if;

if dig7 = 1 then
    case

    when (dig7*10 + dig6)=10 then set ans=concat(ans, ' ten lakh ');
    when (dig7*10 + dig6)=11 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eleven lakh ');
    when (dig7*10 + dig6)=12 then set ans=concat(ans, ' twelve lakh ');
    when (dig7*10 + dig6)=13 then set ans=concat(ans, ' thirteen lakh ');
    when (dig7*10 + dig6)=14 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fourteen lakh ');
    when (dig7*10 + dig6)=15 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fifteen lakh ');
    when (dig7*10 + dig6)=16 then set ans=concat(ans, ' sixteen lakh ');
    when (dig7*10 + dig6)=17 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seventeenlakh ');
    when (dig7*10 + dig6)=18 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eighteen lakh ');
    when (dig7*10 + dig6)=19 then set ans=concat(ans, ' nineteen lakh ');
    else set ans = ans;
end case;

elseif dig7 > 0 then
    case
        when dig7=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' twenty ');
        when dig7=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' thirty ');
        when dig7=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fourty ');
        when dig7=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fifty ');
        when dig7=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' sixty ');
        when dig7=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seventy ');
        when dig7=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eighty ');
        when dig7=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' ninety ');
        else set ans=ans;
    end case;

end if;


if dig6 > 0 then
case
    when dig6=1 then set ans=concat(ans, 'one lakh');
    when dig6=2 then set ans=concat(ans, 'two lakh');
    when dig6=3 then set ans=concat(ans, 'three lakh');
    when dig6=4 then set ans=concat(ans, 'four lakh');
    when dig6=5 then set ans=concat(ans, 'five lakh');
    when dig6=6 then set ans=concat(ans, 'six lakh');
    when dig6=7 then set ans=concat(ans, 'seven lakh');
    when dig6=8 then set ans=concat(ans, 'eight lakh');
    when dig6=9 then set ans=concat(ans, 'nine lakh');
    
    else set ans = ans;
end case;
end if;

if dig5 = 1 then
case
    when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans, ' ten thousand ');
    when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eleven thousand ');
    when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans, ' twelve thousand ');
    when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans, ' thirteen thousand ');
    when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fourteen thousand ');
    when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fifteen thousand ');
    when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans, ' sixteen thousand ');
    when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seventeen thousand ');
    when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eighteen thousand ');
    when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans, ' nineteen thousand ');
    else set ans=ans;
end case;
else
if dig5 > 0 then
    case
        when dig5=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' twenty');
        when dig5=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' thirty');
        when dig5=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fourty');
        when dig5=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fifty');
        when dig5=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' sixty');
        when dig5=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seventy');
        when dig5=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eighty');
        when dig5=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' ninety');
        else set ans=ans;
    end case;
end if;
if dig4 > 0 then
    case
        when dig4=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' one thousand ');
        when dig4=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' two thousand ');
        when dig4=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' three thousand ');
        when dig4=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' four thousand ');
        when dig4=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' five thousand ');
        when dig4=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' six thousand ');
        when dig4=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seven thousand ');
        when dig4=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eight thousand ');
        when dig4=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' nine thousand ');
        else set ans=ans;
    end case;
end if;
if dig4 = 0 AND (dig5 != 0 ) then
    set ans=concat(ans, ' thousand ');
elseif dig4 = 0 AND (dig6 != 0)||(dig7 != 0)||(dig8 != 0) then
    set ans=concat(ans, ' ');
else 
    set ans=concat(ans);
end if;
end if;

if dig3 > 0 then
case
    when dig3=1 then set ans=concat(ans, 'one hundred');
    when dig3=2 then set ans=concat(ans, 'two hundred');
    when dig3=3 then set ans=concat(ans, 'three hundred');
    when dig3=4 then set ans=concat(ans, 'four hundred');
    when dig3=5 then set ans=concat(ans, 'five hundred');
    when dig3=6 then set ans=concat(ans, 'six hundred');
    when dig3=7 then set ans=concat(ans, 'seven hundred');
    when dig3=8 then set ans=concat(ans, 'eight hundred');
    when dig3=9 then set ans=concat(ans, 'nine hundred');
    else set ans = ans;
end case;
end if;

if dig2 = 1 then
case
    when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans, ' ten');
    when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eleven');
    when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans, ' twelve');
    when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans, ' thirteen');
    when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fourteen');
    when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fifteen');
    when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans, ' sixteen');
    when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seventeen');
    when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eighteen');
    when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans, ' nineteen');
    else set ans=ans;
end case;
else
if dig2 > 0 then
    case
        when dig2=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' twenty');
        when dig2=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' thirty');
        when dig2=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fourty');
        when dig2=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' fifty');
        when dig2=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' sixty');
        when dig2=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seventy');
        when dig2=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eighty');
        when dig2=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' ninety');
        else set ans=ans;
    end case;
end if;
if dig1 > 0 then
    case
        when dig1=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' one');
        when dig1=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' two');
        when dig1=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' three');
        when dig1=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' four');
        when dig1=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' five');
        when dig1=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' six');
        when dig1=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' seven');
        when dig1=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' eight');
        when dig1=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' nine');
        else set ans=ans;
    end case;
end if;
end if;

return str_titlecase(trim(ans));
END
$$
```