# Joining table A and table B, both having column1 as common

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables - `TableA` and `TableB`. Both have `column1` as common column.

But in `TableA` data in `column1` is numeric like `201` and in `TableB` data in `column1` is in words like `two hundred one`.

None of the other columns is common.

How can I join these tables? Can I use `to_char(todate(column1,'j'),jsp)` for `TableA`?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435879/converting-numbers-to-words-in-mysql-result-using-query) might help

Comment: You can create another column for numeric version of those words.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle it is possible using this `to_char` function, but in SQL you will need to write a function for this conversion and then pass this function in your query. One such example is `number_to_string` function found on this post.

[Converting Numbers to Words in MYSQL result! Using Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435879/converting-numbers-to-words-in-mysql-result-using-query)

Using this function you can write a condition like

`number_to_string(TableA.numValue) = TableB.stringValue` in your JOIN to obtain the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be appropriate to have some function which convert integer to words, and then you can use standard join clause.

[This link can help you](http://www.novicksoftware.com/udfofweek/Vol2/T-SQL-UDF-Vol-2-Num-9-udf_Num_ToWords.htm)

or

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673265/how-to-write-number-to-word-function-in-sql-server)