# Complex MSSQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help solving this query...

Write a Query Which will display the Student Id and Standard in the format mentioned below.

If Standard is 'V' display 'FIFTH STANDARD', If Standard is 'IV' display 'FOURTH STANDARD',If Standard is 'III' display 'THIRD STANDARD', If Standard is 'II' display 'SECOND STANDARD', If Standard is 'I' display 'FIRST STANDARD' under the column name 'STDINWORDS' and sort by descending order based on standards.

**Hint:**  Query should display the exact string mentioned in the query, such as 'FIFTH STANDARD', etc and use as it is given in the problem statement.
**Example:**
S-125 FIRST STANDARD

**Hint:** 'S-125' is a value of the column StudentID.

Comment: Why is this tagged as mysql?

Comment: @winmutt because my examiner is using mysql for the execution and i thought there might be some inbuilt mysql function to help solve this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look into `CASE` statement for this. Since you didn't provide any sample data, here is one solution based on my understanding:

```
create table student (student_id varchar(255), standard varchar(255));

insert into student values
('S-125','I'),
('S-126','II'),
('S-127','III'),
('S-128','IV'),
('S-129','V');

SELECT student_id
    ,standard
    ,CASE standard
        WHEN 'I'
            THEN 'FIRST STANDARD'
        WHEN 'II'
            THEN 'SECOND STANDARD'
        WHEN 'III'
            THEN 'THIRD STANDARD'
        WHEN 'IV'
            THEN 'FOURTH STANDARD'
        WHEN 'V'
            THEN 'FIFTH STANDARD'
        END AS StdInWords
    ,CASE standard
        WHEN 'I'
            THEN 1
        WHEN 'II'
            THEN 2
        WHEN 'III'
            THEN 3
        WHEN 'IV'
            THEN 4
        WHEN 'V'
            THEN 5
        END AS SortBy_Field
FROM student
ORDER BY SortBy_Field DESC;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b47ca/4/0)

Comment: The answer should be like this :  S-125 FIRST STANDARD

Comment: Thanks anyway.. i found the correct query using your method..                       SELECT concat(student_id
 ,' '
 ,CASE standard
  WHEN 'I'
   THEN 'FIRST STANDARD'
  WHEN 'II'
   THEN 'SECOND STANDARD'
  WHEN 'III'
   THEN 'THIRD STANDARD'
  WHEN 'IV'
   THEN 'FOURTH STANDARD'
  WHEN 'V'
   THEN 'FIFTH STANDARD'
  END) AS StdInWords
FROM student
ORDER BY standard DESC;

Comment: Cool! Now if you could please do me a favor and mark it as an accepted answer since this solution helped you with your problem, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Some combination of these two:

1.) [Converting Numbers to Words in MYSQL result! Using Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435879/converting-numbers-to-words-in-mysql-result-using-query)

2.) http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=30330