# date suffixes mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

im new to mysql. i want to spelled out the day. for example 14th will spelled out as fourteenth. in oracle will be using 'ddspth'. how about mysql? i only know we use '%d' will give out 14 and '%D' give out 14th

Comment: I'm not sure that `DATE_FORMAT` can do this.

Comment: See those tags? Please edit your post and delete the Oracle tag, and on future posts please pay attention to tags. Thank you!

Comment: Similar question: [Converting Numbers to Words in MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435879/converting-numbers-to-words-in-mysql-result-using-query)

Comment: i try that. date_format cannot be use to spell out date

Comment: Date and Number spelling differ. number 1 spelled one. Date 1 spell First

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in function to do this. As you've already mentioned, you could try using

```
DATEFORMAT(date, '%D')
```

to get 1st,2nd.3rd and so on. Or you'll need a `select case` with thirty one cases as follows:

```
            select case Date(date_column)
                when 1 then 'first'
                when 2 then 'second'
                .
                .
                when 31 the 'thirty first'
                else 'INVALID DATE'
            end case;
```

or implement it as a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetDateAsWord(date_column datetime) RETURNS string
```

and return the result of the above statement.