# How to select the maximum value when the field is in text datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has data as shown below. The 'Attempt' column has text entries like First, Second, Third and Fourth

```
entryid User  Attempt
1       1     First
2       1     Second
1       2     First
2       2     Second
3       2     Fourth
4       2     First
```

The output I need is as below

```
UsrID   Attempt
1       Second
2       Fourth
```

As you can see in the case of user 2, even if the latest entry for a user is 'First', since he has an entry for 'Fourth', we need to output Fourth. How can we achieve it?

Currently I'm using four queries to check if a user has any of the entries using EXISTS & NOT EXISTS. I'm then joining their results using UNION. I am also considering assigning each of those statuses a number using CASE WHEN and then taking that new field's maximum. Would anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server here? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Based on what you had explained, why would `UsrID` of 1 return back `Second` attempt?

Comment: @jarlh I have removed mysql tag. I added it because that was recommended.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney Right now the data I am entering is not reflecting correctly when stackoverflow converts it into table. The userID in second row should be 1, not 2.

Comment: You can make an associative derived table, linking the attempt qualification with its rank. Link with that table to get the rank, determine the max rank, and find its associated attempt.

Comment: SQL has no concept of ordinal terms. Store as INTs as others have said.

Comment: @AntonyP, I can't understand that recommendation...

Comment: In spite of having posted an answer on how to tackle this with the table given, I agree that the best - or even the only reasonable - solution is to store numbers instead of ordinal number strings.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't.

Store integer foreign key into your table :

```
UsrID   FkAttemptId
1       2
2       4
```

and make another table with join :

```
AttemptId   AttemptTitle
1           First
2           Second
3           Third
4           Fourth
```

With taht you can make a lot of possibilities like add description or other languages...

```
AttemptId   AttemptTitle   AttemptDescription   AttemptFR    ...
1           First          Bla bla...           Premier
2           Second         Bli bli...           Second
3           Third          ...
4           Fourth
```

Comment: This is nice. Alternately you can write a function that converts English representation to digits and sort use that in your query. You might find some help in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432527/convert-number-to-words-first-second-third-and-so-on)

Comment: Yes, that would be a lot more easier. But, I can't edit the table. I have to work with the data that is available.

Comment: You don't need to *edit* a table in any of these solutions. In @Meloman's solution, you need to *create* a table. In my suggestion, you need to create a *function*.

Comment: @dotNET I can't create a table either. I check if I can get rights to create a function. It's a clients DB and we only get access to query data.

Comment: To create a table OR a function he needs mor right anyway @dotNet ! So the best in this case would be Gordon Linoff solution.

Answer (score 3):

Rank your records with `ROW_NUMBER` and a `CASE` expression:

```
select eid, usrid
from
(
  select eid, usrid,
    row_number() over 
    (
      partition by  usrid
      order by
        case when attempt = 'First' then 1 
             when attempt = 'Second' then 2 
             when attempt = 'Third' then 3
             when attempt = 'Fourth' then 4
             else 5
        end desc
    ) as rn
  from mytable
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by assigning values in a query using a `case` or `join`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by n.num desc) as seqnum
      from t join
           (values ('First', 1), ('Second', 2), ('Third', 3), ('Fourth', 4)
           ) n(val, num)
           on t.attempt = n.val
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I agree with other comments that normalizing the data using a reference table makes more sense.  Sometimes, though, we are stuck with data in a particular format and have to deal with that.  This answer addresses that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a table like that

```
TAB_ATTEMPTS

N Attempt
1 first
2 second
3 third
4 fourth
```

Then you have to join the table that you have with that one joining the two table on the column attempt

```
Select X.USER_ID,T.ATTEMPT from (
  Select  MYTABLE.USER_ID,MAX(TAB_ATTEMPTS.N) AS POSITION FROM 
  MYTABLE (NOLOCK) 
  JOIN
  TAB_ATTEMPTS (NOLOCK) ON MYTABLE.ATTEMPT=TAB_ATTEMPTS.ATTEMPT
  GROUP BY  MYTABLE.USER_ID
) as X
JOIN TAB_ATTEMPTS T ON X.POSITION=T.N
```

That should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a view with a "NumericAttempt" column and then query the view on that column.

```
CREATE VIEW [viewOutput]
AS
SELECT 
entryid,
User,
Attempt,
CASE Attempt
  WHEN 'Fisrt'  THEN 1
  WHEN 'Second' THEN 2
  WHEN 'Third'  THEN 3
  WHEN 'Fourth' THEN 4
  WHEN 'Fifth'  THEN 5
  ELSE 999
END as AttemptNumeric
FROM  TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

or ...if you prefer without the second join...

```
Select X.USER_ID, 
       X.POSITION, 
       (select T.ATTEMPS FROM TAB_ATTEMPTS T where T.N=X.POSITION) AS ATTEMPT 
FROM 
(Select MYTABLE.USER_ID,MAX(TAB_ATTEMPTS.N) AS POSITION 
FROM 
MYTABLE (NOLOCK) 
JOIN 
TAB_ATTEMPTS (NOLOCK) ON MYTABLE.ATTEMPT=TAB_ATTEMPTS.ATTEMPT 
GROUP BY MYTABLE.USER_ID ) as X
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
SELECT a.UsrID, a.Attempt
FROM (SELECT * FROM tattempt a
      JOIN (SELECT 1 AS id, 'First' AS value FROM dual
            UNION
            SELECT 2, 'Second' FROM dual
            UNION
            SELECT 3, 'Third' FROM dual
            UNION
            SELECT 4, 'Fourth' FROM dual) v
            ON (a.Attempt = v.value)
       ORDER BY v.id DESC) a
GROUP BY a.UsrID;
```

where `tattempt` is the name of your table.