# How to get a new column with char data type from the existing int type in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column X in Postgres with values `1`, `2`, `3` ...

How can I get a new column where these values get converted to `one`, `two`, `three` ...

Comment: Try looking at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432527/convert-number-to-words-first-second-third-and-so-on

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples that I've found on the internet

You can try Money to word function
It is a function that returns money, but without decimals works for entire numbers

You can consume the money type function:

```
SELECT replace(cash_words('123'),'dollars and zero cents','');
```

returns

```
"One hundred twenty three "
```

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5192C4DF.7080601%40gmail.com

Other Options I haven't tried:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Integer_to_Text

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Numeric_to_English